# Cannot enter BIOS after installing Ubuntu-Mate 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, boot, dell, bios

I purchased a refurbished Dell Optiplex 755 with Vista (I think) over a year ago.  I installed Linux Mint after booting into Windows once to verify the computer was operational.

Earlier this year I downloaded an ISO from Ubuntu_mate.org and installed it.  Today I tried to upgrade to the latest release with a fresh install.  I was not able to access the BIOS menu.

I tried pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd> on subsequent attempts only to enter the GRUB menu.

Distribution information:

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
Linux jim-OptiPlex-755 3.13.0-61-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I even installed and ran `boot-repair` to no avail.  The information on this is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/1205935.

I have been using Linux for 8 years, however, this problem is beyond my limited expertise.  Any advice and directions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the system is CMOS based, installing an OS wouldn't remove access to the BIOS.

However, the wait period may be so fast you can't press the button fast enough. The first thing to try is resetting the BIOS back to defaults by setting the CMOS bypass, usually a small yellow piece of plastic connected to two of three pins. Move that piece to it covers the other pin an restart your computer.

This should force boot you into the BIOS. Remember to return the bypass piece to its original position.

Comment: I contacted Larry Bushy of the Going Linux podcast concerning the problem.  He contacted an acquaintance who suggested removing the CMOS battery for 10 minutes.  I did and it solved the problem.  Now the BIOS requires me to press F1 to continue with boot process, F2 to enter the BIOS setup or F5 for diagnostic analyses  It is a minor problem because the BIOS cannot see my wireless keyboard.